# SQL query to select all rows with a value included in an array

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an array `projectIds` with `id`s. I want to select all rows from a database that have a value for `project_id` that exists in the array:

```
const { sequelize } = require("./db");  //The db and sequelize work correctly in other places, so can be assumed to be set up correctly.
const { QueryTypes } = require("sequelize");

const projectIds = [1,2,3,4];

let rows = await sequelize.query(
    "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE project_id IN = ?",
    {
        replacements: [`${projectIds}`],
        type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
    }
);
```

The query returns `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error`. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `${projectIds}` evaluates to '1,2,3,4' without the brackets. Perhaps you could write the array directly in the SQL if its safe `WHERE project_id IN [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a try but it still returned the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `(?)` or `(:projectIds)` instead of `?` and pass the `projectIds` array as is:

```js
let rows = await sequelize.query(
    "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE project_id IN (?)",
    {
        replacements: [projectIds],
        type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
    }
);
```

OR

```js
let rows = await sequelize.query(
    "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE project_id IN = (:projectIds)",
    {
        replacements: { projectIds },
        type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Anatoly, I've tried both but still get the error. Catching the error returns: `You have an error in your SQL syntax ... near '= (1, 2, 3, 4)' at line 1  sql: SELECT * FROM 'table_name' WHERE project_id IN = (1, 2, 3, 4) - parameters:[]`.

Comment: I removed `=` from SQL query, it should only `IN`